# jquery appendTo do not work on this correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I want to implement a droplist function which take some parameters and generate a list dynamically like jqueryUI plugin. But I am a little confused about how to add the jquery object to the this object.
Now the code is like this:

```
(function($){
$.fn.dropList = function(options){
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.dropList.defaults, options);
    var cList = $('ul');    
    var list=opts.itemList;
    $.each(list, function(i){
        var li = $('<li/>')
            .addClass('ui-menu-item')
            .attr('role', 'menuitem')
            .text(list[i])
            .appendTo(this);
        console.log(li[0].outerHTML);
    });
    console.log(this[0].outerHTML);
    return this;
};

$.fn.dropList.defaults = {
        name: "",
        position: {x:0, y:0},
        itemList: ['a','b','c']
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And in html, you just invoke like:

```
<div id='list'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#list').dropList({itemList: ['b','f','c']});
</script>
```

Now according to the console.log, it create the li elem correctly, but when I print this[0].outerHTML, the li elements are not attach to it.

The console.log result is like this:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">b</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">f</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">c</li>
<div id="list"></div>
```

I woudl like to insert the li into the div. Is there anyone who can help me figure out the correct way to append the li element to the this object?

Comment: can you provide fiddle or something similar? :)

Comment: Don't forget to use your <ul> element ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `this` pointer.

> More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current
>   DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the iterated element.

as refers from https://api.jquery.com/each/

Store you this before into self variable

```
var self = this;

...

.appendTo(self);
```

Comment: Please don't use the `self = this` hack. Use `bind`, `apply` or `call` properly instead, if you need to make `this` behave like you want the JavaScript way. Or use closures correctly.

Comment: What do you mean about hack? Storing `self` into variable - it's using js closure feature, as you mentioned. Or what do you mean correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In the $.each loop, the value of this will be the item currently being looped through. You can declare "this" into a variable and use it to appendTo.

```
var appendToThis = this;
$.each(list, function(i){
    var li = $('<li/>')
        .addClass('ui-menu-item')
        .attr('role', 'menuitem')
        .text(list[i])
        .appendTo(appendToThis);
    console.log(li[0].outerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using `this` inside another context, so `this` points on the iterable object, not a dropList container.
2. You're defined `cList`, but didn't use it. I think this is a bug, so I fixed it up.

Solution: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brusher/pyv3qre0/2/)